# How do you check if a string contains strings from two tables in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, string, if-statement

I want the console to print true when the message contains one greeting and one name.

Ex. 1 message = ['hey john'] //true

Ex. 2 message = ['yo johnny'] //false

Ex. 3 message = ['hello johnny'] //true

Ex. 4 message = ['hey evan'] //false

```
var message = ['']

var greetings = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
var names = ['john', 'johnny']

if (message.includes(greetings) && message.includes(names)) {
    console.log(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this:

```js
const greetings = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
const names = ['john', 'johnny']
const isIncludes = (msg, arr) => {
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (msg.includes(arr[i])) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false;
}

message = ['hey john'] //true
console.log(isIncludes(message[0], greetings) && isIncludes(message[0], names))

message = ['yo johnny'] //false
console.log(isIncludes(message[0], greetings) && isIncludes(message[0], names))

message = ['hello johnny'] //true
console.log(isIncludes(message[0], greetings) && isIncludes(message[0], names))

message = ['hey evan'] //false
console.log(isIncludes(message[0], greetings) && isIncludes(message[0], names))

message = [''] //false
console.log(isIncludes(message[0], greetings) && isIncludes(message[0], names))
```